# What goes in the Authority field for API Management Identity Provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

**Problem**

I'm in the process of building out an API using Azure API Management Service. I've created an Azure AD B2C tenant by which I'd which to authorize calls to said API.

I was able to setup the tenant successfully; however, I'm running into an issue when attempting to add an Identity Provider of type Azure Active Directory B2C.

I'm following this walkthrough from 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad-b2c

The problem is that something has changed in the actual creation wizard that is not covered in the Azure documentation. There is an additional field that is required: Authority; what goes there?

**What I've Tried**

So far, I've searched the web and the only thing that I could find were ASP.NET applications referencing the following schema for an Authority:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenant}/B2C_1_{signup_policy}

I attempted this (filling in the missing values unique to my tenant and sign-up policy) and I get the error: "One or more fields contain incorrect values: Azure Active Directory B2C authority is not valid."

Can someone tell me what should go there or at least point me in the direction of the updated Azure documentation that does? Again, the linked documentation above is from 2017 and doesn't mention an Authorize field.

Comment: Authority should look like this: `https://{tenantName}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_{signup_policy}/v2.0/` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_{signup_policy}/v2.0/`

Comment: `{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com` can also be replace by the tenant id

Comment: Have you for sure tried this format specifically on the *Add Identity Provider* portion of the API Management Service for a B2C Type? I tried both of the formats that you suggested (of course plugging in the tenant name) and I still get the error. Let's say for example my B2C tenant is contosob2c.onmicrosoft.com, I tried plugging contosob2c into the place holders that you have above for the {tenantName}. No joy; still get the error saying the Authority is invalid.

Comment: No sorry I haven't tried

Comment: No worries. Yeah, it seems like I'm supposed to use some variation of what you shared with me, but the things that I tried are failing. I wish Microsoft would update their documentation.

Comment: have you tried changing `{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com` with the tenant id ?

Comment: Tried that too. I went into the resource for the AAD B2C tenant, copied the Guid-based Id and used that in place of the TenantName. I wonder if there's something else on that form that I'm getting wrong. For example, they ask for a sign-up policy AND a sign-in policy. When I created the policy, both sign-up and sign-in where under the same policy, so I put the same thing for both. I wonder if that's wrong? Also, the sign-in tenant field is simply {tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191930/discussion-between-brandon-avant-and-thomas).

Comment: @BrandonAvant would you please share a link with the steps or something like it about how to create the *tenant*, *application* and *policy*, later add the identity provider to API Management? I'm on the same journey but can't pass the message  `Could not create identity provider
One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Azure Active Directory B2C tenant 'mytenant' or policy 'B2C_1A_signup_signin' does not exist.` but they actually exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authority field is there to control authority of your login URL. For Azure B2C login URL used to start with https://.onmicrosoft.com, recently they've introduced a new primary authority: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin.

This field let's you customize which one you want to use. It should prefil to {tenant}.b2clogin.com, but that seems to be broken. Will be fixed shortly.

Update: I updated your example above the < > characters weren't rendering, so I switched to { }.

Comment: This worked. The authority was simply {tenantName}.b2clogin.com; nothing else. Thanks!